# ワードプレスのwelcartカートボタンカスタマイズに関して

Tags: css, wordpress

ワードプレスにwelcartを設置しています。
カートボタンをカスタマイズしたいと考えています。
CSSに

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.skubutton{
background-image:"http:/画像"
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 443px;
height: 108px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;
overflow:hidden;
display: block;
}
```

を記述しました。

カートのサイズは変更されましたが、画像が表示されません。画像を表示するにはどのように記述を変更すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: BLUEPIXYさん
私の凡ミスでした。
表示されました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

画像のアドレスを`url(`と`)`で囲みます。

例：`background-image:url("画像のアドレス");`